# SubArrays from Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this

```
[[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]]
```

I want the o/p like

```
[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]
```

My function is as follows :

```
DateUtil.setDP([DateUtil.createDP()]) // setDP dummy func.
DateUtil.createDP=function(){
     var arr=  [[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]];
  // I want o/p like 
     return [2014,02,05],[2014,6,9] // Return this format
};
```

So `DateUtil.createDP([DateUtil.createDP()])` will be

```
[[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]]
```

Above will be passed as parameter to function.

Comment: Give more details and scenario. What do you mean by output? you want to print it like that or put it in a variable.

Comment: You are trying to return more than one value which is not possible. You already have array of arrays, so you can do a for like Ron suggested below.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]];
for(var output in arr)
{
console.log(output);
// do whatever you want with this output !
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is what you want:

```
var a = [[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]],
    output = JSON.stringify(a);
output = output.substr(1, output.length - 2, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's all you have to do: pass the function `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.

```
var arr = [[2014,02,05],[2014,6,9]];
function whateverYourFunctionIs(arr[0],arr[1]) {
    // Do stuff with arr[0] and arr[1];
}
```